# Webpage displaying IP Address instead of the domain name

Tags: dns, ip, website, url, tomcat

We have been working on a Tomcat web application which is now live.  Everything is working fine except for the url.  We have purchased the domain name at GoDaddy.  The problem is as follows.

We are able to access the website using something.example.com.  However, when the web page has been loaded and the different links are hovered, the public IP address is being displayed instead of the url: something.example.com

Moreover, I have tried adding the public IP address and the url: something.example.com to my computer's hosts file. Now the web page displays the URL instead of the public IP when hovered.

I am wondering if the problem could be with the setting up of the dns only.

Could anyone help please.

Comment: Feels a lot like the application itself is a bit wonky and links arn't being generated to be relative.

Comment: Any suggestions to make the links relative in Tomcat?

Comment: I don't really do tomcat, I do know some appications I've installed misbehave if you don't set them up from the domain name/path they are supposed to run from.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot.  I will revert back to the developer team.